# RStudio Server not starting

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I have been working in a remote RStudio server for the last few months without any issues. Today, I restarted the rstudio server in using this command

```
sudo rstudio-server restart
```

After this, I am not able to access the server via browser. It keeps on waiting.

I checked the status using this:

```
sudo rstudio-server status
```

This resulted in:

> rstudio-server stop/waiting

My server is configured to run on port 80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution myself

The RStudio server was configured to run on port 80

Kill all the processess using port 80 and then start RStudio server

```
 sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
 sudo rstudio-server start
```

This solved the problem!