# RStudio Server immediately freezes and crashes browser after starting

Tags: rstudio-server

I have an Rstudio Server installation on a Linux Azure VM that seems frozen and also crashes any browser I try to login with.

I have restarted the VM and separately restarted RStudio Server (similarly to the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446316/rstudio-server-not-starting)) a number of times, but it does not change the behavior. I didn't think I had it set to reload an environment or operation upon restart, but perhaps I accidentally did. The last thing I was doing with the server was a large sparse matrix operation that turned out to be too much for it.

Since the problem occurs immediately after the app loads, I'm not sure how to reset its state. I tried following [these instructions](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218730228-Resetting-a-user-s-state-on-RStudio-Server) but it didn't work:

I renamed `~/.rstudio` to `~/.rstudio.backup` while RStudio Server was stopped and it was recreated on the next start, but it still resumed in the same state. I saw mentions of `~/.local/share/rstudio/` and `~/.config/rstudio` in the support docs, but they do not seem to exist in this Azure Ubuntu installation.

I also moved and renamed the folder of the last used R project, but it had no effect. There is a `.config/R/` folder but it only contains a `rsconnect` folder and 2 empty subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it. After shutting down and restarting RStudio Server it was necessary to run this command immediately after RStudio Server loaded:

```
sudo rstudio-server suspend-all
```

Comment: This solution also works well on Rocker/R-Studio docker container. Command can be successfully run as rstudio user.